# Is using multiple sites to get your "free credit score" a bad idea -- do all credit review sites pull from the same data?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit, credit-report

My bank has a free credit score review option. There are several sites that offer it. Does it matter which one you pull from? Do they all pull from the same sources so the data is all the same or does using multiple sites serve as a benefit.

EDIT: This is the united states.

Example:
My bank is Chase but I've been using CreditKarma for example that pulls from two credit companies that look like they follow the same style of ranking.

Comment: If you are in the US, it does matter where you pull from. For example, the tool that Chase advertises pulls from TransUnion, while the one that Discover advertises pulls from Experian, etc. They all have different methods of calculated your credit score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 major credit reporting agencies, Transunion, Experian, Equifax. Using these services has no impact on your score, so no harm in using multiple sites. 
No 2 scores will be identical, but seeing the range of scores will give you a good idea of what a lender will see when you are applying for credit.